# EBS Application slowness but in server level CPU and Memory utilization is normal

Tags: java, oracle, performance, oracle11g, oracle10g

We are using IBM AIX 5.3 OS.
Using EBS Application 12.1.3 with oracle 10 g 10.2.0.4 with RAC environment.

The EBS Application is slow even though CPU and Memory Utilization is normal and in DB also the CPU and Memory Utilization is normal.

There are no locking sessions and blocking session.

The Concurrent Programs are running slowly and even the whole application is slow.

Please anyone let me know why this kind of issue happens and what should be done in such kind of issues.

Thanks !

Comment: SO is for help with programming questions, if you have a problem with your code which we can reproduce, please post it.  Note: EBS is a commercial product so I suggest you get support from the Vendor, if they don't know probably no one does.  Also note, this version is 6 years old, perhaps upgrading will help.

Comment: I won't post an answer, because Peter's right that this is off topic.  I will point out that your description of the problem indicates that you might be making two basic mistakes.  First, you fail to mention disk utilization.  Fast disk (or SSD) is crucial for a high performing database.  Second, you need to be careful about utilization reports that average over a long interval (say 5-15 minutes).  If it takes a user 15 seconds to query a record that should come back in 5 seconds, that's not going to show up on a CPU, disk, or memory utilization report that slices time into 15 minute chunks.

Comment: Look in to AWR tables `dba_hist_filestatxs` and `dba_hist_tempstatxs` for insight into how your disk subsystem is performing.

Comment: Use the DBA% Blitz Reports from https://www.enginatics.com/library/?pg=1&category[]=DBA&app[]=DBA, starting with high level analysis e.g. of total server IO and wait times and then drilling down to problematic SQLs as explained in the presentation here: https://www.enginatics.com/saoug-connect-africa-2017/